# totally random timeouts after session_start() is called

Tags: php, apache, session, iis

I have been trying to fix this wired php session issue for some time now.

Setup: running on IIS V6.0, php for windows V 5.2.6

Issue: 
At totally random times, the next php line after session_start() times out.
I have a file, auth.php that gets included on every page on an extranet site (to check valid logins)

```
auth.php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['auth']==1) { <---- timesout here
       do something ... 
}
...
```

When using the site, I get random "maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" errors at the line 2: if (isset($_SESSION['auth']==1) {

If I modify this script to

```
session_start();
echo 'testing';  <---- timesout here
if (isset($_SESSION['auth']==1) { 
   do something ... 
}
...
```

The random error now happens on line 2 as well (echo 'testing'), which is a simple echo statement, strange.

It looks like session_start() is randomly causing issues, preventing line of code right after it to throw a timeout error (even for a simple echo statement) ....

This is happening on all sorts of page on the site (db intensive, relatively static ...) which is making it difficult to troubleshoot. I have been tweaking the session variables and timeouts in php.ini without any luck

Has anyone encountered something like that, or could suggest possible places to look at ?

thanks !

Comment: Does the user that your website runs as have modify permissions to the `session.save_path` directory?

Comment: This message: maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded, has nothing to do with sessions. This is script timeout parameter, that means, if your PHP script takes too long to execute or generate results(for example endles loop), then it shall stop executing after 30 secs. If you wish you can change this in your .ini setting to a higher value and then check the behaviour of your script. It seems there is some problem with your auth.php file. If you can post that content here, somebody might point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

A quick search suggests that you should be using [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to close the session when you are done using it if you are on an NTFS file system. Starting a session locks the session file so no other file can access it while code is running. For some reason, the lock sometimes doesn't release automatically reliably on Windows/NTFS, so you should manually close the session when you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't know there was such an issue with NTFS! I put session_write_close() in my footer file (included in most pages) and I have seen no timeout errors so far. This may have been the cause of the errors.

I have a question however, if I have a page that takes > 1s to load, and if a user clicks on a link before the footer loads, this potentially could cause a session error am I correct? 

Does this mean I have to call session_write_close(); at the end of every session read/write for each script (instead of calling it form the footer) to minimize these types of errors ?

Comment: Yes you are correct. You could do all your session work at the top of the page, and close the session before starting to output the page. Another option is to look at the [connection handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) documentation. You can configure PHP to ignore user aborts, so your script would still run to the end.